# Comparing two char strings for a password in C

Tags: c, char, passwords, compare

I've been trying to compare two char variables in C, one being the keyword, and the other being the password the user inputs, but despite both being the same, it doesn't let me in. This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<bios.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char pass[4], key[4]="tres";
    start:
    clrscr();
    printf("Write your password: ");
    scanf("%s", &pass);
    if (strcmp(pass,key)!= 0){
        printf("\nWrong password, try again.");
        getch();
        goto start;
    }else if(strcmp(pass,key) == 0){
        printf("Welcome!");
        getch();
        clrscr();
        //here goes the rest of the program
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: 'goto' is a very poor programing construct for implementing a loop.  suggest using do { ... } while;  this line: 'scanf("%s", &pass);' has a few problems: 1) need a length modifier on the '%s' to avoid the user creating a buffer overflow with resulting undefined behaviour and probable seg fault event.  2) the returned value (not the parameter value) needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.   conio.h and getch() are not portable.  suggest  using getchar()   regarding the if/else,  and the result of strcmp() there is no need to call strcmp the second time.

Comment: please indent your code, for the ease of readability of the human reader.  Suggest 4 spaces after every open brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: in general, 'goto' should never be used as it leads to 'spaghetti' code that difficult to follow, error prone, and is never needed.  Use well designed code incorporating if/else, while() and do/while constructs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp` works with null terminated strings.  You need a `\0` character at the end of each string, and each string in this case should be 5 characters long.

Comment: In fact, you are lucky that your program doesn't crash the way it is currently written.  `strcmp` is accessing memory beyond the end of your strings since it didn't find the NULL byte sentinel.

Comment: So what should I use instead? I've been sort of putting it together from what little I could understand in other questions. I've been programming for less than three months so I'm having a lot of trouble.

Comment: As I said, make sure your string is one longer than the size you want to use - and put the null byte there.

Comment: No need to add the `\0` manually. The extra byte is sufficient (using `gcc` on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

```
key[5]="tres";
```

you have to increase the size of array by 1 to store the end of string character `\0`